# UIImageView shows already "deleted" images

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, jpeg

Easy problem for you I guess:

I create an `UIImageView` called by a `UISegmentedControl`. Everything works fine. I have four images, called:

- 1.jpg
- 2.jpg
- 3.jpg
- 4.bmp

Because I wanted to change the displayed pictures / images (whatever) I deleted 1.jpg & 2.jpg out of my project (move to trash / not just delete references) and added two now pictures which I called 1.jpg und 2.jpg too. Xcode shows the correct image file, but after building, I get the old pictures on screen.

I already tried "Reset Content & Settings" in iOS Simulator and deleting the app on my iPad. Did not help anything!

I'm very confused.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you cleaned the target? Images get cached during builds. Product --> Clean in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I Think while deleting the file it will ask you for delete completely or delete reference.
Do not choose "delete reference" as while doing it, It will remove the images from the xcode but the files will be there in the project folder.

After deleting completely. clean the target.
And then you are ready to go with new images. 
enjoy.